# div : how to changethe width

Tags: html, styles, width

At first I used a table, but the pages were slowly
Then I tried to replace the table and use DIV. Wanted to get six columns and found this code:

```
<div id="block" style="width:800px">
    <div id="left" style="float:left;width:16.66%;"> left </div>
    <div id="right" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
     <div id="right2" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
     <div id="right2" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
      <div id="right2" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
     <div id="right2" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
</div>
```

I do not want a fixed width: 800px.
But I want to be relatively across the page (look in the same way any resolution)

Comment: Try to put the style information in css in the future, this makes your code more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

I've moved the inline styles to a stylesheet, to make your life easier. Using `display:table` for the parent and `display:table-cell` for the children, you can spread them evenly, no matter the number of children.

**HTML**

```
<div id="block">
    <div class="column">1</div>
    <div class="column">2</div>
    <div class="column">3</div>
    <div class="column">4</div>
    <div class="column">5</div>
    <div class="column">6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#block div.column {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ch2pk/

Answer (score 1):

Use a percentage instead if you want it to scale well.

e.g.

```
<div id="block" style="width:80%">
<div id="left" style="float:left;width:16.66%;"> left </div>
<div id="right" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
 <div id="right2" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
 <div id="right2" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
  <div id="right2" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
 <div id="right2" style="float:right;width:16.66%;"> right </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx ! but i want to see all 6 columns with Equal intervals between (As you can see in my example)